# Trial (test) lecture as part of the interview process for a tenure-track position

Tags: tenure-track, interview, lecture-teaching-method

I have been invited to give a trial lecture for a tenure track position in Norway. This is part of a hiring process that three top candidates have been shortlisted for the interview.

The lecture should be at master level and I already figured out that the lecture will be open for all interested people. This means that my colleagues including my direct supervisor in my current work (research in a company) will get the invitation link to attend the trial lecture as well. As a result they will know that I have applied for a new position and I have intention to leave my job. This is not a problem *per se* but the problem is that if I don't get the position, I am going to stay in my current job and my colleagues will know the all story.

I am wondering if anyone had the same experience and also is it OK to ask the selection committee that I would like trial lecture to be addressed just for the committee rather than public?

Comment: I doubt that such a request can be honored. But I suspect that your colleagues will understand that you want to optimize your future. They do also. It isn't as if such an application will seem like a desperate move.

Comment: How is the lecture advertised? I'm surprised that you write that your colleagues will get the invitation link. Whom are they sending it to? I'd also guess that it is seen as essential to the process that it's public and that this cannot be changed, however it may not need to be advertised so widely that indeed your colleagues find out with high probability.

Comment: This strongly depends on local culture (and maybe law).  The bottom line is that looking for a new job and/or failing to get one is not a bad thing.  Being a top candidate is an honor.

Comment: @Lewian The company I am working (also other related companies) have offices in the concerned department and we are all part of the mailing list for the weekly seminars, presentations and so on. This means while I am presenting online (because of covid-19), my colleagues know what this is for.